# Unable to sync sharepoint folder to local device

Tags: sharepoint, onedrive

I am trying to sync a sharepoint folder, "Testing" shown in the image below to my local device, but I have not been able to figure out how to do this.

[image: SharePoint]

I have looked at other sources and they said to find the "Sync" option, however I was unable to find this option. How should I go about doing this?

Edit: This is a shared folder that has been shared to me by another person in the organization, and can be accessed by multiple people

Answer (score 0):

Had to read your post a few time but the answer is in the Edit section. The folder was shared to you by another user in the organization. This is most likely the reason why the sync option is not available. I'm a 365 admin in my organization and would make sure that users could not share SharePoint Doc Lib with other users and defiantly not be able to sync the library if the user could share a folder. This would be down to GDPR or Organization policy in place plus SharePoint Libraries will/should have user access in place. Being able to receive a share link from another user to me would mean that there is an issue with access to the SharePoint Document Libraries security/access settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you return to classic SharePoint, you would see the "Sync" option.

To sync sharepoint folder to local device, you have to allow  items from this document library  to be downloaded to offline clients. Please go to library settings-> Advanced settings, make sure you select yes.

[image]